# Radiation pressure at a surface which is perfectly refracting

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, pressure, radiation, radiation-pressure

Radiation pressure at perfectly reflecting surface = 2I/c

Radiation pressure at perfectly absorbing surface = I/c

What will be the radiation pressure at a perfectly refracting surface? Will it be the same as that of perfectly absorbing surface and why?

Comment: What is a perfectly refracting surface?

Comment: you are not giving a link for your assertions, and googling comes up with very complicated behaviors , not simple fomulae. example ;https://www.osapublishing.org/DirectPDFAccess/00695638-98EA-57FB-E492274B0F03679D_119189/oe-14-24-11855.pdf?da=1&id=119189&seq=0&mobile=no